# How to read data from 6th row of an Excel file into SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to import data from 6th row of an Excel file. There are headings from 1 to 5th row of that Excel. When I import data the value is null because I do not have any data in 2nd row of Excel.

```
conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);

using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    excel_con.Open();

    string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

    //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
    dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Name", typeof(int)),
    new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }

    excel_con.Close();

    string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPerson";

            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");

            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bulk copy, you can insert the data in dtExcelData row by row

```
   for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelData.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
        sql = sql + "insert into your_table_name (PersonId, Name, Salary) values('"
              + dtExcelData.Rows[i]["Id"].ToString().Trim() + "','"
              + dtExcelData.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString().Trim() + "','" 
              + dtExcelData.Rows[i]["Salary"].ToString().Trim() + "')";
    //execute the sql here in try catch
     }
```

Comment: I was trying this .
                using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "$" + "A7:ZZ]", excel_con))
                {
                    oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
                }
                excel_con.Close();  But got the error as The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$$A7:ZZ'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

Comment: I got the solution. i just changed my code as  using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "A6:F]", excel_con))